# How to create page content from a taxonomy using DRUPAL

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm pretty new using Drupal, and I have a doubt.

I have a category with some categories inside: Services (main category) that has child categories (books, newspapers, letters).

Each child category has an image, a title and a short description for it. I created a taxonomy, called **Services**, and I added the child categories as terms. (I don't know if this is the correct way for doing this. Any suggestion will be accepted and thanked).

Now I want on home page to show something like this:

[image: what I want to show]

So, I want a grid view of my sub-categories on my home page with the image and the title, and when I click it, go to the sub category and show its content.

Sorry for not being more specific, but I'm really newby...

Comment: You've marked this as Drupal 6 _and_ Drupal 7...it can't be both!

Comment: Why not? it's a generic topic!

Comment: Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 are two completely different systems, to make this question answerable you need to tell us which one you're using. Otherwise this question is at best too generalised, and at worst two completely separate questions. Which version are you using?

Comment: Forgive my ingorance, as i told I'M NEWBIE... but thanks for negative vote ¬¬

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your vocabulary looks like this:

```
[Category]
- Sub-category 1
 - term 1
 - term 2
- Sub-category 2
 - term 3
 - term 4
- Sub-category 3
 - term 5
etc.
```

and while you create your terms you also add a description for each sub-category term.

So, to output only first-level terms (sub-categories) you should create a page/block with [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) module.

While creating a new View, be careful to choose `Show: Taxonomy terms` above the "Adding new view" form and select your vocabulary.

Then, in order to output only level-1 terms, you should add relations - press Advanced/ Relationships and choose `Taxonomy term: Parent term`. Then add new `Filter criteria` - `Taxonomy term: Parent term` with `Relationship` set to `Parent` and `Operator` set to `Is empty (NULL)`

To add description simply add new field - `Taxonomy term: Term description`.

All other customization (wrap title in  tags, output fields as table/grid and so on) are also available in views.

I've not tried to add an img to terms so far, but I guess there are to ways to accomplish that: via CSS (by adding 'background:' property) or by using some modules such as [Taxonomy Image](http://drupal.org/project/taxonomy_image).

PS

If it matters, all above is about Drupal 7, and I'm not absolutely sure will it work on Drupal 6 or not.